# Creating barcode from font Free 3 of 9

Tags: c#, .net, barcode

This is my code to create barcode image:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateBarcode("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".ToUpper());

        }

        private static void CreateBarcode(string code)
        {
            var myBitmap = new Bitmap(500, 50);
            var g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
            var jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            g.Clear(Color.White);

            var strFormat = new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center };
            g.DrawString(code, new Font("Free 3 of 9", 50), Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, 0, 500, 50), strFormat);

            var myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
            var myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

            var myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L);
            myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
            //MemoryStream memoryStrem = new 
            myBitmap.Save(@"d:\Barcode.jpg", jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
        }

        private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
        {
            var codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

            foreach (var codec in codecs)
            {
                if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
                {
                    return codec;
                }
            }
            return null;
        } 

    }
```

This works fine however, this line: `g.DrawString(code, new Font("Free 3 of 9", 50), Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, 0, 500, 50), strFormat);`

as you can see the width here is 500. Now if I specify a big paragraph of text I fear that 500 would not be enough. Is there any way to make this width dynamic based on content?

Comment: Would `g.MeasureString()` or something like that suffice?

Comment: Cool but then how do I change this line? var myBitmap = new Bitmap(500, 50); The bitmap here is of 500 * 50. Shouldn't that also be dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Its too old to answer, Still am posting as it may help some one. We can create graphics object with a dummy bitmap and try find the length of font, after than re-initialize the bitmap as well as graphics object.

```
var myBitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1);
Font threeOfNine = new Font("Free 3 of 9", 60, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
var g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
SizeF dataSize = g.MeasureString(code, threeOfNine);
myBitmap = new Bitmap(myBitmap, dataSize.ToSize());
g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
```